# Firebase/Google analytics 28d user count do not match `session_start` 28d user count

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, firebase-analytics, looker-studio, firebase-console

I am trying to sort out why the user count coming from Firebase?Google Analytics does not seem to match the user count for `session_start`. We have a number of clients on the app and I am filtering by the client ID here so they can see how many users/sessions they have.

The is the user count for the last 28 days:

[image: Here is the user count according to Firebase/GA]

This is the same time period looking at Google data studio:

[image: Here is the data from Google Data studio for the same time period]

Why don't the number of users for `session_start` match the number of monthly users?

Also, why is it so difficult to get the number of sessions from Firebase/GA? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

By default `session_start` event is fired "when a user engages the app for more than the minimum session duration after a period of inactivity that exceeds the session timeout duration" ([docs](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9234069)) so the number of `session_start` events doesn't necessarily match the overall number of users

Comment: But how could there be more users than sessions? If they do not use the app how do they get counted as a user?

Comment: default "minimum session duration" is 10s https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/analytics/FirebaseAnalytics.html#setMinimumSessionDuration(long) so if user engages with an app for a less time this interaction won't be reported as 'session' but pops up in events and user reports

Answer (score 0):

I *think* I might have sorted out why that client's numbers were off. From what I can gather, receiving a notification counts that person as an active user, even if they do not open the app at all.

[Here is the SO post I came across trying to sort this out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44501358/google-analytics-for-android-users-that-receive-notifications-are-counted-as-ac)